# Get rows having consecutive Month range in SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need to extract consecutive dates of a particular installation and reject all installations that does not have consecutive dates.

for example

The following is my query:

```
SELECT
    Installation_no
    ,RDNG_STTS_CD
    ,UPDTD_DT
    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Installation_no ORDER BY UPDTD_DT ASC) AS RowNum
FROM
    mrdg_tbl_download_DailyBKP
WHERE
    RDNG_STTS_CD = 'PL';
```

that resulted in the following data:

```
+-----------------+--------------+-------------------------+--------+
| Installation_no | RDNG_STTS_CD |        UPDTD_DT         | RowNum |
+-----------------+--------------+-------------------------+--------+
|      5000002099 | PL           | 2018-05-14 11:47:01.050 |      1 |
|      5000002099 | PL           | 2018-05-14 11:47:01.050 |      2 |
|      5000002101 | PL           | 2018-06-19 14:39:33.633 |      1 |
|      5000002101 | PL           | 2018-06-19 14:39:33.633 |      2 |
|      5000002101 | PL           | 2018-07-19 16:07:23.723 |      3 |
|      5000002101 | PL           | 2018-07-19 16:07:23.723 |      4 |
|      5000002110 | PL           | 2018-01-04 15:49:08.017 |      1 |
|      5000002110 | PL           | 2018-01-04 15:49:08.017 |      2 |
|      5000002187 | PL           | 2018-01-23 14:51:59.160 |      1 |
|      5000002187 | PL           | 2018-01-23 14:51:59.160 |      2 |
|      5000002187 | PL           | 2018-03-25 12:39:43.343 |      3 |
|      5000002187 | PL           | 2018-03-25 12:39:43.343 |      4 |
|      5000002187 | PL           | 2018-04-27 16:31:20.420 |      5 |
|      5000002187 | PL           | 2018-04-27 16:31:20.420 |      6 |
|      5000002187 | PL           | 2018-05-29 17:54:20.520 |      7 |
|      5000002187 | PL           | 2018-05-29 17:54:20.520 |      8 |
|      5000002187 | PL           | 2018-06-28 17:10:12.613 |      9 |
|      5000002187 | PL           | 2018-06-28 17:10:12.613 |     10 |
|      5000002438 | PL           | 2018-01-31 16:03:38.137 |      1 |
|      5000002438 | PL           | 2018-01-31 16:03:38.137 |      2 |
|      5000002438 | PL           | 2018-03-04 15:19:41.340 |      3 |
|      5000002438 | PL           | 2018-03-04 15:19:41.340 |      4 |
|      5000002438 | PL           | 2018-04-04 16:45:01.040 |      5 |
|      5000002438 | PL           | 2018-04-04 16:45:01.040 |      6 |
|      5000002438 | PL           | 2018-05-07 15:58:54.553 |      7 |
|      5000002438 | PL           | 2018-05-07 15:58:54.553 |      8 |
|      5000002438 | PL           | 2018-06-07 14:26:45.647 |      9 |
|      5000002438 | PL           | 2018-06-07 14:26:45.647 |     10 |
|      5000002438 | PL           | 2018-07-10 15:53:54.753 |     11 |
|      5000002438 | PL           | 2018-07-10 15:53:54.753 |     12 |
+-----------------+--------------+-------------------------+--------+
```

The above is a sample data. and i have around 200 000 records in each category (here category is 'PL')
I need a distinct installation having consecutive month range (month 1,2,3,4,5).

I have tried every example in stack overflow but could not get precise answer.

Comment: Can you have multiple installations on the same day?

Comment: Can you please add the desired result you want to have?

Comment: Please define "consecutive month range". Does this mean they have to have dates spanning at least more than 1 month? And there cannot be gaps in the months? Is there a minimum or maximum to the number of months allowed?

Comment: 1. Yes, Multiple installations will always be there,
2. Consecutive Month(as i have already mentioned) Month 1, Month 2, Month 3, Month 4 , Month 5 and Month 6, I need 6 consecutive months filter.
3. Sometimes, the category ('PL') can have gaps for example that category can exist in Month 1 and not in Month 2, This data I do not need, I only need consecutive data.

I will post the desired result in some time.. Thank you for your reply

Comment: Desired Result:

Installation_no UPDTD_DT RDNG_STTS_CD
5000026931 2018-01-06 13:41:21.120 PL
5000026931 2018-02-06 14:14:04.023 PL
5000026931 2018-03-08 15:09:08.037 PL
5000026931 2018-04-08 12:49:31.430 PL
5000026931 2018-05-11 12:55:59.560 PL
5000026931 2018-06-12 13:16:55.657 PL
5000026931 2018-07-13 20:19:03.073 PL


The following query resulted in above data:
select distinct Installation_no,UPDTD_DT,RDNG_STTS_CD from mrdg_tbl_download_DailyBKP where Installation_no = '5000026931' order by UPDTD_DT

Comment: I have not recieved any update regarding this

@StackOverflow: What to do now, should i post the question again?